# g ++ How to fix this?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw-w64

`findpattern.cpp:1:5: error: 'i' does not name a type
  ■# i n c l u d e   " f i n d p a t t e r n . h "
     ^
findpattern.cpp:27:2: error: 'D' does not name a type
          m b i . R e g i o n S i z e ,   N U L L ) ;
  ^
findpattern.cpp:83:2: error: 'v' does not name a type`

c:\minGW\mingw32\bin\g++ -c findpattern.cpp

Comment: This looks like an UTF-16 (with even a BOM at start) file being fed to gcc... That's not supported, use UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that you saved the file in the right encoding.  Some Windows editors default to UTF-16, and this can cause problems like that.  You need to select UTF-8 instead.